# How to run a program for a fixed period of time?

Tags: command-line, scripts, timeout

*I am looking for a method built-in to ubuntu that will allow me to run a script or program or whatever for a fixed period of time.*

[I found a program that does this in a way I like](http://prefetch.net/blog/index.php/2007/04/29/running-processes-in-fixed-time-intervals/), but the package is unavailable for Ubuntu. In any case, I was hoping for something built-in.

The only thing i can think of is to get the current time and set a cron job 30 minutes from 'now' that will kill the program.  I was hoping there was a way to do this without setting up a script, but if I need to - it wont be the end of the world. After the 30 minute interval I would like to put my laptop in a sleep mode, but this can be separate from the timer thing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run application for a set time in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456405/how-to-run-application-for-a-set-time-in-shell)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've just wrote the following and it seems to work:

```
ping google.com& PID=$!; sleep 3; kill $PID
```

Of course you should substitute ping with the command you want to run and 3 with a timeout in seconds. Let me know if you need a more detailed explanation on how it works.

Comment: This exits in a syntax error after '&;'. For example just running 'vlc &;' gets the same error; but I see what you are trying to do...

Comment: Sorry about that, I tested it on Zsh instead of Bash. It works when you remote the semicolon, corrected.

Comment: Well when i remove the semicolon it doesn't get the PID. I get: 'bash: kill: $!: arguments must be process or job IDs'. It does TRY to kill it after 10 seconds though...

Comment: Just remove the backslash before `!`. Once more sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 18):

Why not use `/usr/bin/timeout`?

```
$ timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple (and not much tested) version of `hatimerun`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

help(){
    echo "Usage"  >&2
    echo "  $0 -t TIME COMMAND" >&2
    exit 1
}

TEMP=`getopt -o t: -n "$0" -- "$@"`

if [ $? != 0 ] ; then 
    help
fi

eval set -- "$TEMP"

while true ; do
    case "$1" in
    -t) timeout=$2; shift  2;;
    --) shift; break;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "$timeout" ]; then
 help
fi

cmd="$*"

$cmd&
echo "kill $!" | at now+$timeout
```

See the [manpage of at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/at.1.html) for how to specify the time. Like with `at` the minimum time resolution is 1 minute.

Another way is [to use upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stopping-a-job-if-it-runs-for-too-long) instead of this script.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl:

```
perl -e "alarm 5; exec @ARGV" systemctl list-timers
```

Using timelimit command:

```
sudo apt install timelimit    
timelimit -t5 node app.js
```

Using timeout command:

`timeout -sHUP time command`

Comment: That's already in https://askubuntu.com/a/102328/760903

Comment: @Olorin now the post is edited by OP including another solutions as well as a sample of the `timeout` command.

Comment: @αғsнιη  Do you mind answering a short query about timeout and timelimit command? When I used timeout and timelimit command, it gave me error like this after it exited from that timeout period. 
```myname@myname:~$ myname@myname:~$ myname@myname:~$ myname@myname:~$``` For each enter, it kept making in the same line instead of going to another line. Then I had to exit from the session and login again. But, perl command worked fine without giving any error.

Comment: sorry, I have no idea what's happening there

Comment: `tput reset` solves this problem