# How to run application for a set time in shell

Tags: command-line, scripts

If and How is it possible to, in `Terminal`, to get an application to run for 30 seconds, before being force closed, and echoing the logs of that process?

Comment: @JacobVlijm It would ideally run as a shell script due to the portability of the language, mainly as the intended area of usage is a CI service.

Comment: @ir-g you can use the _timeout_ command. e.g. _timeout 30s command_

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might want to use the *timeout* command.

```
timeout -k 10s 30s command
```

which will run the command for 30s and kill it after 10s if still running. - Check the manpage for more options.

Comment: @ir-g you're welcome. You might also want to check out the _watch_ command, which is similar and also very easy to use in the command line.

Comment: Thanks for that pointer, `watch` strikes me as a very interesting command. Could come in handy...

Answer (score 3):

Here are two ways (but the `timeout` command [suggested by mcantsin](https://askubuntu.com/a/456410/85695) is probably better):

1. Launch the command in the background, that way its PID is saved in `$!` and you can use that to kill it after the specified time:

   ```
   command &
   sleep 30 && kill $!
   ```
2. Launch the command and use `pkill` or `killall` to kill it. CAUTION: This assumes that only one command with that name is running, I am using `firefox` as an example:

   ```
   firefox &
   sleep 30 && pkill firefox
   ```

I have no idea what you mean by "the logs of that process" but a process's standard error can be saved to a file with `command 2> logfile.txt`.